# How to programmatically add a "more" link?

Tags: 7, views

In the Views UI (in the center column), we can select "More link" which provides a checkbox to "Create more link." Selecting this returns a link for more results of the view.

How would I programmatically add this "more" link? That is a link to all results of a Drupal 7 view?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) Unfortunately it's absolutely unclear what exactly you want. Maybe you can edit your question and provide more context information? Many thanks

Comment: leymannx, thank you for your reply. In the Views UI (in the center column), we can select "More link" which provides a checkbox to "Create more link." Selecting this returns a link for more results of the view.

I would like the function which offers this functionality.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information. And I'd recommend to add more context as well. What's wrong with doing it from the UI? Why do you need to add it programmatically?

Comment: The client is running what is essentially a homespun version of https://www.drupal.org/project/features_override and wants site-specific overrides to the Features (in this case, a view) in code while ensuring updates to the Features do not overwrite these settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow -3 rating? This was intended to be an authentic question.

Not ideal, but my solution was to render a static link in the View's footer:

```
   // Render "more" link in footer 
    $footer_options = array(
    'label' => t('Footer text'), // Administrative label.
    'content' => '<a href="/link/to/display">View All Events</a>', // Content of footer text.
    'format' => 'filtered_html', // Format of text.
    'empty' => 0, // 0 hides footer if view is returning no results; 1 sets footer to always display.
  );
  $view->add_item('default', 'footer', 'views', 'area', $footer_options);
  }
}
```